# Deselect checkbox in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, ionic-framework

I am using the following code:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{{F}}" ng-model="IsChecked" ng-change="ModifyFilter(IsChecked,$index)">{{F}}
```

with the Controller:

```
$scope.ModifyFilter = function (IsChecked, index) {
  if (IsChecked) {        
    $scope.ActiveFilters.push($scope.Filters[index]);   
  } else {
    var indexz = $scope.ActiveFilters.indexOf($scope.Filters[index]);
    $scope.ActiveFilters.splice(indexz, 1);
  }
  $scope.ApplyFilter();
};
```

This works fine, however I am unable to deselect my checkboxes. This is in the browser and iOS when built with ionic.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to send IsChecked to the function. Simply write in controller $scope.IsChecked.
However create a $scope.CheckboxValue in controller, bind that variable in ng-model and modify $scope.CheckboxValue accordingly to your logic.
Hope this helps.